# Cumulative distribution function for simulated random value

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose we draw 3 cards out of standard 52-card deck. X is the random variable representing the number of different suits in our hand. Then we multiply X by random variable Y in the range [0,4] giving Z. How cumulative distribution function for Z will look like?

**Added:**
I think the distribution of X is following:
\begin{array}{c}
X &1 &2 &3\\
p &\tfrac{22}{425} &\tfrac{234}{425} &\tfrac{169}{425}
\end{array}

And random variable in range [0,4] is real number in range [0,4] (continuous uniform distribution).

**Added:**
Finally I end up with this:
$$Z=\sum_{x_i<x}p_i\cdot \frac y4$$

Comment: What do you know about the distribution of $X$?

Comment: Also "random variable in the range $[0,4]$" is very vague. Do you mean integers in $[0,4]$ only? What kind of distribution? Uniform perhaps? Your question lacks a lot of elements to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that $$\mathbb P(Z<a)=\mathbb P(Y<a)\mathbb P(X=1)+\mathbb P(Y<\frac{a}{2})\mathbb P(X=2)+\mathbb P(Y<\frac{a}{3})\mathbb P(X=3)$$

And for ($0\le a\le 4$) $$\mathbb P(Y<a)=\frac{a}{4}$$

Hence $\mathbb P(Z<a)$ will be defined by a linear piecewise function on $[0,4]\cup[4,8]\cup[8,12]$